# How to pronounce the notation $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty \\ y \to \infty} F(x, y) = 1$

Tags: limits, notation, pronunciation

How does the following notation read in plain English:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty \\ y \to \infty} F(x, y) = 1$$

As far as I can read:

> 1. If $x$ and $y$ approaches $\infty$, the value of function $F(x, y)$ approaches $1$.
>      i.e.
> 2. The value of the function $F(x, y)$ is $1$ somewhere near but before $(x, y) = (\infty, \infty)$.
> 3. The $limit$ of the function $F(x, y)$ is $1$ at $(x, y) = (\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: The function doesn’t have to actually equal $1.$ it just has to approach it.

Comment: Are you assuming that both $x$ and $y$ tend to $\ infty$ or, as usual, that at least one tends to $\infty$?

Comment: You should clarify what are the conditions on $x$ and $y$ to be more precise.

Comment: I would use "$x$ and $y$ each independently approach $\infty$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is correct. (2) and (3) are not.

What you write as "$(\infty, \infty)$"  makes no sense. Infinity is not a number, and there is no place with those coordinates, so it makes no sense to ask for the value of $F$ there.

Informally: the values of the function $F$ are as near to $1$ as you please everywhere outside a circle of large enough radius. The value may never actually be $1$. Think about the function given by
$$
F(x,y) = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} .
$$

**Edit.** There is in fact some ambiguity about whether we are looking at the two variables $x$ and $y$ as independently large and positive, or whether the OP intends to ask about what happens when $||(x,y)||$ is large. In either case (2) and (3) make no sense. Assertion (1) will be correct if the ambiguity is resolved by the context.

Comment: edited 2 a little bit.

Comment: @yahoo.com Still not correct.

Comment: edited again...

Comment: @yahoo.com Still not correct! The function never has to equal 1.

Comment: x and y are independent of each other.

Comment: (1) is the only nearly correct reading. You could say "independently approach " instead of "approaches". I've no more to add to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

By the following

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty \\ y \to \infty} F(x, y) = 1$$

it seems you are referring to a case where both $x$ and $y$ tends to positive infinity as for example

$$F(x,y)=1+\frac1x+e^{-y}$$

and the first sentence is preferable to decribe that situation "when both $x$ and $y$ approch $\infty$ then $F(x,y)$ approches $1$".

Note that in the standard definitin of limit at $\infty$ we are requiring that $\|(x,y)\| \to \infty$ and in that case we can say that the "limit of $F$ is $1$ as $x^2+y^2 \to \infty$" that is

$$\lim\limits_{x^2+y^2 \to \infty} F(x, y) = 1$$

Comment: "... as $x^2+y^2\to \infty$" would allow one of $x$ and $y$ to remain bounded (even constant) while the other approaches $\infty$ alone. It would also allow either to approach $-\infty$. In any case, it is not a correct rephrasing of the given limit.

Comment: @Blue That's the standard notation for limit of two or more variables at $\infty$. Since we have no other information I'm referring to that. I'll ask to the OP fro a clarification on that point.

Comment: I disagree. "$x^2+y^2\to\infty$" gives no information about $x$ or $y$ (or their signs) individually, whereas the stated limit explicitly requires each value to approach (positive) infinity.

Comment: @Blue I understand your point but I'm not sure that the OP is referring to that. I've already asked a clarification. We'll return on that later. Thanks

Comment: Even if only one variable has to go to infinite, squaring the values is problematic. The proper formulation in that case would seem to be something like $\max(x,y)\to\infty$.

Comment: @Blue Again: according to the standard definition the limit at $\infty$ for function of several variables correspond to the assumption $\|(x,y,..)\| \to \infty$ for that reason I'm referring to that. In the OP there is not any other indication from which we can deduce different set up. Anyway I've asked for a clarification and we'll check again taht issue once the OP will give more information. You could ask to him too instead to repeat again the concept here. It is clear to me. Thanks

Comment: @gimusi: Regarding "according to the standard definition the limit at $\infty$ for function of several variables", what you said is true. However, the ***notation*** used by the questioner is NOT this concept, and the notation virtually always means (and I'm only including "virtually" to be super-safe) "$x \rightarrow \infty$ **and** $y \rightarrow \infty$" (also written as $(x,y) \rightarrow (\infty,\infty) ).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for your kind explanation. I don't exclude that but I'm not sure of that and for that reason I've asked a clarification to the OP, indeed this a key  point to be clarified fro a correct answer.

Comment: @gimusi: If you google "double limit" some, you'll find examples supporting (at least) "sometimes means", and I have yet to find an example otherwise. See [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1935-41-08/S0002-9904-1935-06133-6/S0002-9904-1935-06133-6.pdf) (unfortunately old, and thus may not be convincing for current usage) and the notationally analogous usage in [this paper](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/S0002-9947-1984-0735410-1.pdf) (top of p. 98).

Comment: @Blue I've revised according to you observations including both cases. Thanks

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro  I've revised according to you observations including both cases. Thanks