# How to pronounce the notation $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} F(x, y) = F(a^+, y) = F(a, y)$

Tags: limits, notation, pronunciation

> *Related:* [*How does the notation of limits read in plain English?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2922692/366312)

How does the following notation read in plain English:

I can't interpret it myself.

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} F(x, y) = F(a^+, y) = F(a, y)$$

Comment: Where have you encountered the notation $F(a^+,y)$? There is a standard interpretation for the limit notation $\lim_{x\to a^+}$, but I'm unaware of any standard meaning for the superscript plus sign elsewhere.

Comment: @BarryCipra, [Hwei Hsu. Page-80. *C. Properties of $F_{XY}(x, y)$*](https://www.dca.ufrn.br/~affonso/FTP/livros/Hsu_probabilidade.pdf)

Comment: OK, the superscript plus sign notation $F(a^+)$ appears, and is explained, at the bottom of page 39.

Comment: @BarryCipra, `and is explained, at the bottom of page 39.` ---. Then tell me what is $\lim \limits_{0<\epsilon \to 0} a + \epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit as $x$ approaches $a$ from the right (values greater than $a$) of $F(x,y)$ equals $F(a^+,y)$ ($a$ is evaluated at its right-hand limit) equals $F(a,y)$.